# Notifications for file system events (Jailbreak devices)

Tags: ios, file, filesystems, jailbreak, cydia

I need to be able to receive notifications when there is a new file system event.
For instance when a new picture is added. I need to be able to receive these notifications for the whole filesystem not just the sandbox my app is in. This is for devices with jailbreak?

Does anyone know which private API should I use?

My app is a daemon app and runs in the background and it has to be able to receive these events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS actually makes this really easy for you.

I don't know what **else** you might want your daemon to do, but if you only wanted it to stay alive continuously to watch for new picture files, then you have another alternative.

You can configure a Launch Daemon to be started, only when new file system events are detected.  [See the Apple docs on (OS X) Launch Daemons here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-SW8)

Your launch daemon executable can then just be a simple `main()` program.  It will be started by the system when a new picture file is written, and you can then use `NSFileManager` or `ALAssetLibrary` to check the directory for the newest file(s).  You might want to save a preference that indicates when the last time the daemon was run, to make sure you keep track of all new files.

```objc
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // if we're here, we know there's a new picture, so use
    // NSFileManager to check for photos
    // or, see something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/9730973/119114 ... 

    // and then we exit the process and let launchd start us
    // again when there's more pictures

    return 0;
}
```

The key here is to use a `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.MyApp.plist` file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
    <key>Label</key> 
    <string>com.example.MyApp</string> 
    <key>ProgramArguments</key> 
    <array> 
        <string>/Applications/MyApp.app/MyDaemonExecutable</string> 
        <string>optional_argument_one</string>   <!-- passed to main() as argv[] -->
        <string>optional_argument_two</string>   <!-- passed to main() as argv[] -->
    </array> 
    <key>WatchPaths</key> 
    <array> 
        <string>/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE</string>                
        <string>/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE</string> 
    </array> 
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Comment: this seems pretty cool! The only downside is that I have to manually add all the paths I want to watch for but since I want to watch only for video, images and maybe audio this shouldn't be a stopper. Will get back to you as soon as I test it!

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka, I'm afraid there's no reasonable way to get around *that* problem.  You wouldn't want your daemon to listen for changes to *every* file in the filesystem.  iOS is constantly writing files, as it works in the background.  Your daemon would be getting called too often if it listened to everything, so specifying just the folder you want is going to be a good idea, no matter how you solve this problem.

Comment: thanks this seems to work well! I have one follow up question before I close this thread. My daemon is launched once after device reboot and it starts a repeating task so I need it to continue running. Then when a picture is taken the daemon is launched again. What happens with the previous process started after device boot? Is is killed or two separate processes are running together?

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka, you would probably have two separate processes running together.  I say *probably* because I don't know what else your daemon does.  If your daemon starts up, and tries to acquire a resource (file, well-known port, etc.), and exits if it can't get exclusive access, then the second instance will die.  But, if you haven't coded it that way, I'd expect to see two daemon processes.  If you need to have one true daemon alive at all times for some other work, maybe you should create two executables: one always-on daemon, and a second small executable that just gets called ...

Comment: ... by launchd when the Camera Roll folder is changed.  This second executable is just a simple program to handle the file system notification, scan for the newest pictures or videos, and then exit.

Comment: And if you want to try to keep almost all your logic in the daemon that stays on at all times, then your second executable could simply be a one-line main program that does nothing but forwards a custom notification to be received by the daemon.  For example: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { notify_post("com.mycompany.filesystemnotification"); return 0; }`  The daemon would then register a callback handler for the `com.mycompany.filesystemnotification` event, and use that to decide when to do its work.

Comment: Yes you are right. There are two processes running. This whole approach won't make it easier for me as I need to scan and see which is the new photo/video added. I will probably end up using a polling mechanism on those directories and check the files last modified/created property. Thanks anyways this was really useful for me.

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka, I understand that you still need to write some code to list the  directory contents, and sort them by modification date.  But, that sounds like about 15 lines of code, at most.  Keep in mind that if you code your daemon to **poll**, you'll be duplicating a feature that iOS has built-in (this path *watch* feature in my answer), and your implementation will almost certainly be less responsive (more delay after files are added), and consume more battery.  For a service that's always on, that may not be a great tradeoff.  Just something to consider ...